# Generate formatted friendly URL from RouteData

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to programmatically map a query string to an SEO friendly route URL I've created within my `RouteConfig.cs` file but appear to be having difficultly.

My route configuration looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ReviewPost",
    url: "{year}/{month}/{filename}/",
    defaults: new {controller = "ReviewPost", action = "Detail"},
    namespaces: new[] {"ApplicationName.Website.Controllers"},
    constraints: new {year = @"\d{4}", month = @"\d{2}"}
);
```

And I'm able to retrieve the correct `RouteData` object like so:

```
string url = "~/ReviewPost/Detail/?year=2015&month=05&filename=review-title";
RouteData routeData = RouteDataUtils.RouteByUrl(myUrl);
```

However I'm having difficulty figuring out how to generate the friendly URL that should look like the one specified in my configuration (`/2015/05/review-title/`).

Is the `RouteData` object able to create an instance of the formatted URL above, or do I have to format it myself? Or does the MVC framework have a class for correctly formatting the URL string using the `RouteData` object?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear: you are saying that when you try the url involving ReviewPost/Detail/2015/5/review-title, it currently is not working?

Comment: The URL is working. I'm trying to programmatically turn the unformatted query string (`~/ReviewPost/Detail/?year=2015&month=5&filename=review-title`) into the formatted query string within my configuration (`/2015/05/review-title/`). I've just updated my answer for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Try it this way:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper();
var theUrl = urlHelper.RouteUrl(routeData.Values);
```

**original**

Try something like this:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper();
var theUrl = urlHelper.RouteUrl("ReviewPost",routeData.Values);
```

Note that the first parameter to `RouteUrl` is the name of your route--i.e. how you named it in `MapRoute`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I will not have access to the Route's name. As I'm doing this programmatically I will only have the full URL to go by.

Comment: there are other versions of the method. try calling with just route data.values. just that one parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try when I'm at my computer.

Comment: How'd that go the second way?

Comment: Sorry, I've been meaning to get back to you. It did the job perfectly! It also looked my route was having difficulty parsing the month (05) as an integer. As soon as I changed it to a string it started to work as expected. Thanks for your help!